# Basic transactional DDL script in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transaction, plpgsql, ddl

PostgreSQL newbie here trying to put together a transactional DDL script to atomically create a database and its schema in Postgres 9.3: in a transaction, create a few tables; if any errors, roll the whole thing back; otherwise commit. I'm having a hard time getting the syntax right, and I suspect my problems might stem from conflating SQL DDL with PL/pgSQL and/or not grokking the transaction semantics.

Long story short, what's the PL/pgSQL boilerplate for a script to do something like this?

My attempts have gone something like `schema.sql` here:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah ( ... ); -- much DDL

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK; -- this, I gather, is PL/pgSQL

COMMIT;
```

`\i schema.sql` at the psql prompt produces a syntax error at or near `EXCEPTION`. OK, so `EXCEPTION` must be PL/pgSQL, and all this needs to go in a PL/pgSQL declaration. Let's try again:

Per the grammar at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-structure.html, this looks like:

```
[ <<label>> ]
[ DECLARE
    declarations ]
BEGIN
    statements
END [ label ];
```

I don't need to name this, it's a one-off provisioning script, not declaring a function I'm going to use again. So skip the declarations and expand `statements` to what I had before:

```
BEGIN

    BEGIN;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah ( ... ); -- much DDL

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK; 

    COMMIT;

END;
```

This blows up in even worse fashion, with syntax errors on `BEGIN`, `EXCEPTION`, and then it keeps running the rest of the script anyways, complaining about not being in a transaction.

What's the misunderstanding I have here?

Comment: You are trying to run a PL/pgSQL block. You need to wrap that into a `DO` statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if any errors, roll the whole thing back;

It's simpler than you seem to think. Any exception in a transaction (that is not trapped somehow) triggers a `ROLLBACK` for the whole transaction *automatically*. You don't have to do *anything* extra.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blah ( ... );
-- much more DDL
COMMIT;
```

Before Postgres 11, one could not start, commit or roll back transactions ***inside*** PL/pgSQL code blocks at all, which is *always* run in the context of an outer transaction automatically. With the addition of SQL `PROCEDURE`, `COMMIT` is allowed now, but still not in functions. See:

- [COMMIT works in one plpgsql code block, but not in another?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290931/commit-works-in-one-plpgsql-code-block-but-not-in-another/290944#290944)

Don't confuse [SQL commands for transaction management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html) with elements of a [PL/pgSQL code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html). `BEGIN` is used as keyword in both, that's the only thing in common. That's never ambiguous, because the SQL command is (still!) not available inside PL/pgSQL code and there are no PL/pgSQL commands outside PL/pgSQL code blocks.

An [`EXCEPTION` clause in a plpgsql block is only used to trap errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) and do something before or instead of the `ROLLBACK`. Of course, it only makes sense to *do* something that `ROLLBACK` isn't going to *undo* - like [raising a message](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html), signaling or writing to the log.
You don't need any of this for your demonstrated code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use exception and commit as the block itself is transactional. So the following block will not produce anything in case of exception.

> `DO $$BEGIN  create table a(aa int); create table b(aa int);perform pg_sleep(10); create table c as select 1/0 from a; END$$;`