# Trap exception in PostgreSQL script

Tags: postgresql, transaction, rollback

I want to run a script inside a transaction in PostgreSQL. So I surround the SQL code with `begin` and `commit` statements. But I want to `rollback` on error. I don't see how to do that.

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE public.tablename
SET blah = 'xxx'
WHERE thing= '123';

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126477/195925).
The rollback will happen when an error occurs without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You set a `savepoint` and after the comand a `Rollback`

> ```
> CREATE tABLE tablename (blah varchar(3), thing varchar(3))
> ```

> ```
> BEGIN;
> SAVEPOINT my_savepoint;
>    UPDATE tablename
>    SET blah = 'xxx'
>    WHERE thing= '123';
> ROLLBACK TO my_savepoint;
> COMMIT;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da6bcaf043b14148343119a6c9abfb3c)*

Comment: Yes: That's nice, I can test my script that way, Thank you.