# Is ROLLBACK; on error automatic in a basic PostgreSQL DDL script (BEGIN; <STATEMENTS;> COMMIT;)?

Tags: postgresql

I want to run numerous statements in an atomic transaction on a Postgres database. Is it sufficient to put `BEGIN;` at the start of the script and `COMMIT;` at the end of the script? I want to ensure that if an error occurs during the transaction, it's automatically rolled back.

For example, I have the script test.sql:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT
    *
FROM
    intentional_error;
CREATE TABLE faketable (fakecolumn TIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
```

`intentional_error` is not a real table in my schema, so I expect the first statement in the transaction to error. When it errors, I'm wondering if `faketable` will be created.

From my research, I can't find Postgres docs that clearly state that a `ROLLBACK;` is automatic in this scenario. There is a [Stack Exchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126477/241442) that states that `ROLLBACK;` is automatic, but I would love to see a test or something from the Postgres docs.

Comment: If you want it documented, write to the pgsql-docs mailing list. Ideally, submit a patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this question on a Postgres database (version 12.44). I created the file test.sql (same as in the question):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT
    *
FROM
    intentional_error;
CREATE TABLE faketable (fakecolumn TIMESTAMP);
COMMIT;
```

This was the output from CLI.

```
-d postgres -f test.sql -W
Password: 
BEGIN
psql:test.sql:5: ERROR:  relation "intentional_error" does not exist
LINE 4:     intentional_error;
            ^
psql:test.sql:6: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
```

Then I double-checked that the table wasn't created.

```
$ psql -h my-host -U postgres -d postgres -W
Password: 
psql (15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg22.04+1), server 12.14)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \d faketable
Did not find any relation named "faketable".
```

In conclusion, putting `BEGIN;` at the start of the script and `COMMIT;` at the end of the script is sufficient to `ROLLBACK;` the transaction in the case that  one of the statements errors.